# Add fitted quadratic curve

Tags: r, lm

I'm trying to add a fitted quadratic curve to a plot.

```
abline(lm(data~factor+I(factor^2)))
```

The regression which is displayed is linear and not quadratic and I get this message:

> Message d'avis : In abline(lm(data ~ factor + I(factor^2)), col =
>   palette[iteration]) :   utilisation des deux premiers des 3
>   coefficients de régression

which means:

> Use of the first 2 of the 3 regression coefficients

When running only the `lm()` function I don't get any messages.

Here is a sample data:

```
factor <- 1:7
data <- c(0.1375000,0.2500000,0.3416667,0.4583333,0.7250000,0.9166667,1.0000000)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using [`abline`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/abline.html), use [`fitted`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/fitted.values.html), which gives you a vector the same length as your input of the predictions:

```
fitted(lm(data~factor+I(factor^2)))
#         1         2         3         4         5         6         7 
# 0.1248016 0.2395833 0.3699405 0.5158730 0.6773810 0.8544643 1.0471230
```

Thus, something like:

```
plot(factor, fitted(lm(data~factor+I(factor^2))), type="l")
```

Comment: I think it's helpful to know that this works more consistently (i.e., with numeric variables) when you `sort` both X and Y variables in `plot` (i.e., the original X value and the fitted data) .  --> `plot(sort(x), sort(fitted(lm(y~x+I(x^2)))), type = 'l')`

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get answers so far to work, as dataset I used has x-values which are not increasing (as stated by David Robinson above).  Here's how I solved it...

```
require(ISLR)
plot(mpg~horsepower, data=Auto)

# fit the model
glm.fit = glm(mpg~poly(horsepower,2), data=Auto)

# create 100 x-values based on min/max of plotted values
minMax = range(Auto$horsepower)
xVals = seq(minMax[1], minMax[2], len = 100) 

# Use predict based on a dataframe containing 'horsepower'
yVals = predict(glm.fit, newdata = data.frame(horsepower = xVals))

lines(xVals, yVals)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all these valuable answer. Be carefull:

Use

## Use predict based on a dataframe containing 'horsepower'

```
yVals = predict(glm.fit, newdata = data.frame(horsepower=xVals)
```

## Use predict based on a dataframe containing 'horsepower'

```
yVals = predict(lm.fit, newdata = data.frame(horsepower=xVals)
```

`lm.fit` is a function